# numpy.dtype=object very slow compared to numpy.dtype=int

Tags: python, numpy, object, int

I am entering high values (greater than 2^70) inside numpy arrays using numpy.dtype=object:

```
numpy.array([1], dtype=numpy.object) << 70
array([1180591620717411303424], dtype=object)
```

The only reason I am using dtype=numpy.object here is that numpy.int's limit is crossed when you try to enter high values inside it.

```
numpy.array([1]) << 70
>>> array([64], dtype=int32) #the result should have been array([1180591620717411303424], dtype=object)
```

The details is expained in my other question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52301276/integer-limit-crossed-while-performing-bitwise-left-shift-operation-in-array/52301348?noredirect=1#comment91551805_52301348). In such cases using dtype=object works fine.

But I found that using dtype=numpy.object is very slow.

To verify, I compared the timings of the following operations:
[image]

You can see that dtype=int is much faster.

So is there any workaround for entering high values inside numpy arrays?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html, your best options are probably `uint64` (still too small), or using double precision floating point.

Comment: What is the larger picture here? What are you trying to achieve with these large numbers?

Comment: I am building a bit map index of person vs videos, where I have a lot of videos(more than 1000) for a limited set of people (about 100). So each cell represents whether that person appears in the video(1) or not(0). This table is stored in a file. Now when I want to know if two people appear in a video together or not, then I read the corresponding row for those two people and do a bitwise 'AND' operation to get the result and locate the indices where there is '1'. So do this bitwise 'AND', I need to convert the binary list into integers first and then compute the result.

Comment: Use a pair of uint64 values per video of you must have bit masks. You can define a custom dtype like that if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the user's comment:

> I am building a bit map index of person vs videos, where I have a lot
>   of videos(more than 1000) for a limited set of people (about 100). So
>   each cell represents whether that person appears in the video(1) or
>   not(0). This table is stored in a file. Now when I want to know if two
>   people appear in a video together or not, then I read the
>   corresponding row for those two people and do a bitwise 'AND'
>   operation to get the result and locate the indices where there is '1'.
>   So do this bitwise 'AND', I need to convert the binary list into
>   integers first and then compute the result.

A *much* simpler solution would be to load the binary array (dummy data used here, shape = persons x videos), then compare the two rows corresponding to your two persons (say person 10 and person 37) using &, and finally retrieving the video indices where both occur:

```
my_map = numpy.random.randint(0,2,(100, 1000), numpy.bool)
appear_together_in_video_index = numpy.where(my_map[10] & my_map[37])
```

This way you are only ever dealing with booleans (8-bits) and avoiding the large number issue completely.

To answer the original question, it is not really a fair comparison. Since your aim is to work with large numbers, you should perform the timing tests between two solutions that support such large numbers. The basic alternative is to hold Python ints in a Python list, which is not faster (nor simpler to handle) than to store them as objects in numpy arrays.

Comment: Also, can we optimize? like if I want to find the videos where all the people appear together? That will be 'AND'ing each row of my_map matrix. So, can we simply 'AND' each row of the matrix, just like we do np.sum(axis=0)? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Yes, you can do my_map.all(axis=0).

Comment: Thank you @Benjamin! You are truly awesome!